# Texmaker don't compile latex document on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, latex, texmaker

I'm using ubuntu, and i'm trying to compile some latex documents, but i'm getting a lot of errors. I think that compiler is installed, but i'm not sure. I used Latex before on Windows, with Miktex, but installing it on linux appear don't work.

Someone know how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, whathaveyoutried.com and what error message do you get?

Comment: Have you set the path? Try putting the direct path to the compiler in settings.

Comment: The path is correct, there are like 1000 of errors that don't found ttf and fonts, but paths are ok.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what I did:

1-  Install Latex compiler:

```
sudo apt-get install abntex
```

2-  Install TexMaker:

```
sudo apt-get install texmaker
```

3-  Run texmaker and load your Tex document

And you install next, too

```
sudo apt-get  install texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended texmaker
```

Answer (score 8):

You can install all dependencies just using `sudo apt-get install texlive`

Answer (score 4):

As I said in [Install LaTeX on Ubuntu or Debian](http://milq.github.io/install-latex-ubuntu-debian), I use the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

And then:

```
sudo apt-get install texmaker
```

Note that the installation of the full Tex Live distribution take a long time, but I recommend it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use

`sudo apt-get install texlive`

if you prefer to only download packages as you need them. Using

`sudo apt-get install texlive-full`

will download 2GB of data that extracts to an install of over 4GB!